# Calling a static template method from a template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to do a template method that calls a template static method of another class, but I get some compiling errors. The minimal case is the following.

If I compile the code below

```
template<class E, class D>
int foo() {
  return D::bar<E>() + 1;
}
```

it throws the following output

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -c
test.cpp: In function ‘int foo()’:
test.cpp:4:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   return D::bar<E>() + 1;
                  ^
test.cpp:4:20: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   return D::bar<E>() + 1;
```

When I replace `D::bar<E>` with `D::bar`, the compilation pass so It seems there is some parsing problem with the template argument of the function. Like other cases I think it needs some `using` or `typename` hack to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify that the dependent name `bar` is a template:

```
return D::template bar<E>() + 1;
//        ^^^^^^^^
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9693d2eb22143288)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more information about the `typename` and `template` keywords.